# Is there a read out loud plugin for Firefox 4 or latest Chrome version?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firefox-extensions, google-chrome-extensions, text-to-speech

Is there a read out loud (text to speach) plugin for Firefox 4 or latest Chrome version?
I'm talking about a functionality similar to what exists in Adobe Acrobat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Firefox you could try [Speak it](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/3552/), but you need windows. Another option for Firefox is [Fire Vox](http://www.firevox.clcworld.net/). Chrome has the [Page reader extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jbldhmenlfmbooleglopeplanhpmhmje).

Comment: Thx! I actually found that Speak it also exists for Chrome and it works perfectly!!

Comment: Here is the link for Speak it for Chrome: [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pgeolalilifpodheeocdmbhehgnkkbak#)

Comment: Glad it works for you.